# Static float with initializer possible?

Tags: objective-c, static, floating-point, xcode5, extern

I want to do something like this in Obj-C. Example:

```
extern float TRANSITION_TIME = 0.5f;
```

Or even better:

```
static float TRANSITION_TIME = 0.5f;
```

So then it is automatically imported with headers!

However, both give some kind of warning: `'extern' variable has an initializer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate the declaration like this

```
extern float TRANSITION_TIME;
float TRANSITION_TIME = 0.5f;
```

Although the situation is different, there's a nice explanation in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090354/why-does-initializing-of-an-extern-variable-locally-inside-a-function-give-an-er).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easily as this :

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

static float TRANSITION_TIME = 0.5f;


@interface ClassName : NSObject
 ...// rest of codes goes here
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to define a *single* variable `TRANSITION_TIME` which is accessible in multiple locations and defined & initialised in one location.

There is a parallel here with a function or a method - you place a declaration for the function or method in a `.h` file, which is included in multiple locations; and define the function/method in a `.m` (or `.c` etc.) file, i.e you give it a value in one location.

To define your variable you follow the same pattern. In your `.h` file you declare your variable:

```
extern float TRANSITION_TIME;
```

you need to use `extern` to indicate this is a declaring a variable defined elsewhere[*] . Then in your `.m` file you provide the definition:

```
float TRANSITION_TIME = 0.5f;
```

[*] For function/method declarations in the `.h` the lack a body is sufficient to indicate the function/method is defined elsewhere and `extern` is assumed. However for functions you can also include the `extern` at the start of the declaration (the syntax for methods does not support this redundancy).