# extern throwing "both extern and initializer" error

Tags: c++, extern

In this code **`i`** has been defined (and it has been initialized despite being `extern`). Now the book I am reading says:

> An *extern* declaration may be defined only if it appears to be
>   outside a function.

and it offers no reason behind it.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    extern int i=898;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have gone through the question (similar to this one on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090354/)) but the explanation doesn't appear to be clear. The question is:

How are these two **definitions** different at function scope:

1. `int i=898;`
2. `extern int i=898;`

In both the cases a single unit of `int` size memory is being allocated. Is it due to linking error? Please answer clearly as (IMO) it hasn't been satisfactorily in older version whose reference has been used to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @EdHeal that line in the book caught my attention & hence this question was asked.

Comment: One is legal (and therefore means something) the other one is illegal (and therefore doesn't mean anything).

Comment: The `extern` says 'the variable is defined somewhere else' (and specifically, not in this function); you can't control how that variable defined somewhere else is initialized — the somewhere else that defines the variable may have different views on how it should be initialized.

Comment: Maybe it's similar to extern const that might have an initializer to be used in constant folding.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How is extern int i=898; illegal as it is allowed to be done outside a function (which throws a warning).

Comment: @infinite What do you think it should mean? The reason it's not legal is because there is nothing sensible for it to mean.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you please confirm this (this line is from one of the answers) -> "The extern keyword keeps the compiler from allocating memory for the variable indicating that memory for the variable will be resolved at link time in global scope.". It this happens, is it despite using initializers with extern?

Comment: @infinite The `extern` keyword means different things in different contexts. That is the gist of the idea it expresses, but it's not a precise explanation that applies to every use.

Answer (score 0):

The *extern* keyword keeps the compiler from allocating memory for the variable indicating that memory for the variable will be resolved at link time in global scope.  Your link to the other answer was not available so I answered.